# HTML style.backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, background-image

I was trying to make an effect, where if your cursor enters the div (button), an image in another div is changing. It's a part of my code:

```html
<div class="button" onmouseenter="button1()">
  <a href="oserwerze.htm">
    <p class="button-c">O SERWERZE</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
function button1() {
  console.log("button1()");
  document.getElementById("menu-imgs").style.backgroundImage = "url('../ img / wariant1.png');"
}

function button2() {
  document.getElementById("menu-imgs").style.backgroundImage = 'url("../img/tapet.png");'
}
```

CSS:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20, 20, 20, 1) 20%, rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3) 90%),
url('../img/tapet.png');
```

Idk what is wrong here.

I was trying to it with linear-gradient() and without it but it still wasn't working. It should change the image.

Comment: might be issue with space in url - url('../ img / wariant1.png');

Comment: Yes. The path is incorrect due to spaces within it.

Comment: Could you make your code into a simple working snippet. In particular, what element gets that CSS, what does that element look like? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As @PrinceSodhi said:

> might be issue with space in url - url('../ img / wariant1.png');

I assume that your folder is named `img`, rather than `_img_`, and your image is named `wariant1.png`, rather than `_wariant1.png`.

To fix this, try replacing:

```js
url('../ img / wariant1.png');
```

to:

```js
url('../img/wariant1.png');
```

That should do it!